# Can I use imagettftext more than two times per image?

Tags: php, gd

I googled this a lot and couldn't find an answer, is there some kind of limitation to imagettftext() in PHP GD Library? I called it three times on the same image but the third doesn't seem to appear. How can I "draw" three imagettftext() on the same image?

Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:
I use this function to generate a border:

```
function imagettfstroketext(&$image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, &$textcolor, &$strokecolor, $fontfile, $text, $px){
    for($c1 = ($x-abs($px)); $c1 <= ($x+abs($px)); $c1++){
        for($c2 = ($y-abs($px)); $c2 <= ($y+abs($px)); $c2++){
            $bg = imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $c1, $c2, $strokecolor, $fontfile, $text);
        }
    }
    return imagettftext($image, $size, $angle, $x, $y, $textcolor, $fontfile, $text);
}
```

Then I set the variables from the HTML form:

```
$text = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($_GET['text'])));
$text = str_replace('&gt;', '>', $text);
$text = str_replace('&lt;', '<', $text);
$text = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $text);
$text = str_replace('and_sign', '&', $text);

$text2 = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($_GET['text2'])));
$text2 = str_replace('&gt;', '>', $text2);
$text2 = str_replace('&lt;', '<', $text2);
$text2 = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $text2);
$text2 = str_replace('and_sign', '&', $text2);

$text3 = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($_GET['text3'])));
$text3 = str_replace('&gt;', '>', $text3);
$text3 = str_replace('&lt;', '<', $text3);
$text3 = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $text3);
$text3 = str_replace('and_sign', '&', $text3);
```

More variables:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng('images/'.$base.'.png');
$size = '12';
$angle = '0';
$font = 'font/' . strip_tags($_GET['font']) . '.ttf';
if (!$_GET['font']) $font = 'font/visitor2.ttf';
```

And then I use the function to draw the text:

```
imagettfstroketext($image, $size, $angle, 4, 12, $text_colour, $text_outline, $font, $text, 1);
imagettfstroketext($image, $size, $angle, 10, 20, $text_colour, $text_outline, $font, $text2, 1);
imagettfstroketext($image, $size, $angle, 4, 30, $text_colour, $text_outline, $font, $text3, 1);
```

Comment: Personal experience, I saw it used more then 3 times on the same image and no problem whatsoever. Could you share the code you used? maybe there's an error in the third call, or in how you do those in the first place

Comment: I added the code, it seems that I can use imagettftext but I can't use that function I copied from the internet three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation on the function, you can use it as much as you want on any image. Maybe you are just trying to write outside of the image with bad coordinates or the color of the text is the same as the background so you can't see it.

Anyway, I advise you to print to a file the variables used by the function when it doesn't work to see if all is right.